# How to call html on click of a div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to call a text area on click of a specific div, eg i have a div and when the user clicks on the div, the text area appears.

i would also like to make 3 divs and when each one is clicked, different html elements are shown, for example, one one div is clicked, the text area is shown, when another div is clicked a submit button is shown in the same area that the text area would be shown in

Please help! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make elements visible and invisible by changing their style.display attribute in javascript.

A css value of display:none will make an element invisible.
A css value of display:block will make an element visible, and it will be treated like a block element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textarea {
    display:none;

    position:absolute;
    left:180px;
    top:0px;
    width:180px;
    height:130px;
}
#div {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:180px;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea">Tada</textarea>
<div id="div" onclick="showTextArea()"></div>
</body>
<script>
function showTextArea() {
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i would also like to make 3 divs and when each one is clicked, different html elements are shown, for example, one one div is clicked, the text area is shown, when another div is clicked a submit button is shown in the same area that the text area would be shown in

Comment: Just make all the html elements have a style attribute of display:none; Add click listeners to the div, and when they're clicked, get the invisible element with the document.getElementById (or similar function) and change its style.display property to "block".

Comment: how do you set an click listener?

Comment: Personal opinion: if you want to provide the full code consider to do this the right way. 1. Place the script block *inside* <body></body> and 2. add a <title>. Thanks.

Comment: @Guandalino Well, it works :) Why would putting the script tag in body be the 'right way' by the way?

Comment: @Daniel Feinstien there are several ways to add event listeners, but I used an inline one on the div element: <div id="div" onclick="showTextArea()"></div>

Comment: Yes, it works, I tried it also! :) But IMO this code is not a good example because it doesn't pass W3C validation.

Answer (score 1):

Write your text in a javascript functions which you attach to the onclick event of your div.

Answer (score 1):

This may work...

```
<script language="Javascript">
function divClicked()
{
    document.getElementById("txtView").style.display = 'block'; 
}
</script>

<div id="txtView" style="display: none"><textarea></textarea></div>

<div onclick="javascript:divClicked();">Click on This Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to make a textarea appear upon clicking on a div.

You could use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) for that.

Put your textarea in a hidden part (use style display:none), and then use the jQuery [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function to make the textarea appear.

(Or you could write your own function that changes the display style)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
    <textarea style="display:none;" id="idArea">blabla</textarea>
    <div id="idDiv"></div>


    <script>
    $('#idDiv').click(function(){
      $('#idArea').show();
    });    
    </script>
```